# XCode 4.5.2 behavior

Tags: xcode

I have a question regarding XCode 4.5.2 IDE behavior.  Let's say I have a Project called 'HelloWorld', XCode creates the folder 'HelloWorld' and a subfolder within it called 'Resources', when I drag files or .png files into the 'Resources' folder, in the Finder these files are located in 'HelloWorld' folder instead.

I did not have this behavior when using Xcode 4.2.  Is this normal??

Thanks!

Leo;

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is normal and has been like this as long as Xcode 4 has been around, AFAIK. The resources folder is added as a 'Group' within the Xcode project file. It is just a way to organize your files within Xcode, even though the files are all just added to the main project folder in the back.

To get proper file organization, you will want to manually create your folders at the project folder level. Then you can create the groups within Xcode and relink your source files according to whatever scheme you have in mind.

Keep in mind, if you move your files around at the OS level, not Xcode, the file linkage will likely break in Xcode. This will turn the file red like Xcode can't find the file. Typically I will just delete the file from Xcode, then add it back, creating a folder reference to the file rather than letting Xcode copy the file back (which would create a duplicate and defeat the purpose).